# Compilation Error while editing the visual studio solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I am editing a visual studio MVC Solution. I have edited all the files, assemblies and Project Name etc. But in the end, it is build successfully but when I am going to run this solution it shows an error like shows in the picture.

Actually, TestSolution was the name of my solution which I've changed with RealEstateErp.Now when I am going to search "Using TestSolution " , I don't find anything. Now, what should I do to overcome this problem? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should remove line 28 from your Index.cshtml

Comment: still shows the error on line no 28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, It was on the Web. Config under View Folder.

I've Updated it with the latest solution name and now it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

when they make drastic changes like the namespaces and dll names, the first thing people forget is to delete the old dlls.

I would start with that, make sure you delete everything in bin, obj and all temp files which reside in Windows\Microsoft.Net and then Framework and Framework 64.

Next, check your global.asax file, specifically the front end part. You get to it by right-clicking the global.asax file and selecting the "View markup" option, that one always has a reference to the old namespace and always gets missed.

Finally, make sure you delete all the using statements referring to the old namespace. You don't need those and they will cause a compilation error like the one you are seeing, because that particular namespace does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do Ctrl+Shift+F and search your whole solution about `Using TestSolution`?

You probably will find the word left somewhere.

Comment: I'd already done Ctrl+Shift+F but o dont find anything even i'd delete all the temp files too.